# How to use java map (java/util/Map) in C++ using JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I need to call a java class function which returns a map of string as key and a list of class object as value. I am calling java function from c++ using JNI.

I have successfully called the function and stored the returned java map in a JNI 'jobject' variable. Now I need to iterate over elements in map and use their values, but not able to find how to do that.

The structure of java map is like

```
'Map<String, List<ErrorLogger.ErrorObject>>'
```

Where ErrorLogger is 'public interface ErrorLogger' and ErrorObject is defined in ErrorLogger as 'public static final class ErrorObject'.

In C++ Code : I am getting this map in jmapobj

```
//Create Map object
jclass clsMap = env->FindClass("java/util/Map");
jmethodID constructorID = env->GetMethodID(clsMap, "<init>", "()V");
jobject jmapobj = env->NewObject(clsMap, constructorID);

//Call method
jmapobj = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(Cls, method, arg);
```

Could someone please help me with it.

Comment: Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and provide some code. It is much easier to answer if shown code

Comment: @MauriceRandomNumber thanks for pointing that out. I have added the  code please help me with the problem.

Comment: Sorry, no time for a proper answer. You need to call the Java methods to iterate over the map using `GetMethodID` and `Call..Method` as you did to get the Map in the first place.

Comment: You probably want to create an instance of a concrete implementation of `Map`, such as `HashMap` (just like you would in Java).

Comment: Your code replaces the newly allocated `jobject jmapobj` by the one returned by the Java function. You don't need to "create" a Map, the Java function gives it to you. Then you may try to call the `values()` method or the `entrySet()` method on that object.